# package R does not exist…or does it?

Tags: android

These errors are displayed in random order:

```
error: package com.*.* does not exist

error: package R does not exist
```

These errors will not always be displayed, but will occasionally be displayed and should be to run again to be fixed.

Comment: Can you post your log here

Comment: Clean your project , go to toolbar Build--> clean project. if this does not solve your problem,please post your log so that we can help you in better way.

Answer (score 1):

- ***option 1:*** You just clean and rebuild project
- ***option 2:*** File -> invalidate catches and restart

If those things does not work,
just check your log errors carefully, You did a simple mistake in your layout designs or java classes or somewhere else.